# Python if statement to match lists of tuples - removing duplicates

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tuples

I am attempting to pull data from MySQL database on a 10 second interval.  Since the amount of data coming in every second is variable, I plan on pulling the most recent 50 rows every 10 seconds.  My first function works well and pulls the data appropriately.

My second function is supposed to remove duplicates from the previous pull and only push uniques to the new variable, but I am encountering an error and not sure how to fix it.  It seems like for my if statement I am not allowed to match all elements of each tuple.  I'm not really sure how to change this.

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import requests
from operator import itemgetter
import time

run = True

def sqlPull():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXX', password='XXXXX', host='XXXXXX', database='MeshliumDB')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI FROM wifiscan ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 50;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    time.sleep(10)
```

The data output looks like this:

```
[(104346, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 20), u'00:1E:4C:03:C0:66', u' 16'), (104345, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 20), u'00:1E:4C:03:C0:66', u' 16'), (104344, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 19), u'00:26:AB:BB:FB:B8', u' 17'), (104343, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 18), u'8C:2D:AA:42:0E:67', u' 17'), (104342, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 17), u'E4:CE:8F:3F:36:E0', u' 13'), (104341, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 16), u'00:1E:8F:75:82:35', u' 9'), (104340, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 16), u'00:1E:8F:75:82:35', u' 9'), (104339, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 15), u'74:44:01:31:D9:E2', u' 9'), (104338, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 19), u'84:38:35:5E:F8:BA', u' 8'), (104337, datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 14, 17, 43, 15), u'00:26:08:E2:38:F9', u' 8')]




def dupCatch():
    lastPull = []
    for TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI in data:
        if TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI not in lastPull
            data = newData
            else
            lastPull = data

while run == True:
    sqlPull()
    dupCatch()
    print newData



  File "<ipython-input-1-6d9d5eb980c9>", line 20
    if TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI not in lastPull
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `if (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) not in lastPull`

Comment: would you mind explaining to me why i need to do this?

Comment: The `()` force the values inside to form a tuple. Python does this automatically in most situations, except apparently while checking conditions in if-statements. My guess is that this way of expressing your if-statement is simply not part of the python grammer

Comment: @inspectorG4dget why not make this an answer, so it can be upvoted and commented on?

Comment: @ASGM: I wasn't entirely sure that I had the right answer, which is why I didn't feel it was answer-worthy. But, I've posted it anyways, so please check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally a comment, but it seemed to be helpful, so I'm reposting it as an answer:

The comma syntax tells python to create a tuple, yes. This is why the following two behaviors are identical:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = L
```

and

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
(a, b, c) = L
```

However, I suspect that this doesn't always apply, for instance in the case of expressing a condition in an if-statement or a loop. This might be indicative of such expressions not being part of the python grammar itself; but not to worry, as the grammar can be edited in the source code (I know for a fact that this is possible, but the citation escapes me at the moment), which can subsequently be compiled into your own flavor of python.

For the time being, however, you want to force those variables to be gathered into a tuple, so that you can check for the existence of that tuple in the set. To that end, try this:

```
if (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) not in lastPull:
  # do stuff
```

**EDIT**: I checked [the grammar](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html?highlight=grammar) and this does really seem to be the case.